# MySQL kill process is user don't got enough points PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

The coding below works like when a user clicks submit, he get one ticket (lodd) and loses five points because he bought one ticket for five points. But I miss when a user don't get five points he can't buy. I want that if the user doesn't get enough points then an echo says (example):

> Sorry, but you need at least five points to buy a ticket.

How can I do that? Now people only go in minus if they buy more than they have.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //=============Configuring Server and Database=======
    $host        =    'localhost';
    $user        =    'root';
    $password    =    '';

    //=============Data Base Information=================
    $database    =    'login';

    $conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information is not Correct'); //Establish connection with the server
    mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

    //===============End Server Configuration============

    //=============Starting Registration Script==========


    $username    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtusername']);

    //=============To Encrypt Password===================

    //============New Variable of Password is Now with an Encrypted Value========


    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
    mysql_query($insert);

    // Other code

    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `lodd` = (`lodd` +1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
    mysql_query($insert);

    mysql_query($insert);

    header('location: succes.php');
?>
```

This is the code that give people one ticket for five points:

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert);

// Other code

$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `lodd` = (`lodd` +1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
mysql_query($insert);

mysql_query($insert);
```

Comment: You'd want to do a select query, most likely... "how many points does the user have now?"

Comment: @MarkB - There is no need to for an extra select query here. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, mysql_* are deprecated so you should look at changing them at some point. One option is to use: [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Back to your question, you could do this:

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-5) WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and points > 5";
mysql_query($insert);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{
    // other codes

    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `lodd` = (`lodd` +1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
    mysql_query($insert); 
}else{
    echo "You don't have enough points";
}
```

Comment: THanks alot worked great!:)