# mysql update mysql info

Tags: php, database, insert, sql-update

i got a point system where people can buy diffrent things for points they get. Now i'm going to make so people can upgrade to [PRO] user. when they register they get logged in mysql as [user]. I'm making a code so that after action they lose 50 points and their [user] get replaced with [PRO]. but now i'm, with the replacement with [pro]. this is the code i have:

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-50) WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and points > 50";
mysql_query($insert);
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
{

    // other codes

  $insert =  "UPDATE users SET rights=' [user]'  WHERE rights=' [pro]' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
    mysql_query($insert); 
header('location: succes.php');
}else{
    echo "You don't have enough points to upgrade to [PRO]";
}
```

Comment: what is the result you are seeing?

Comment: Side note: is $username is safely escaped before using in the first line of your code?

Comment: @nappingrabbi: i dont got result... maby thats why?-.-

Comment: 2nd side note: if user have =50 point, can he get pro? May by you first line of code condition should be `WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and points >= 50"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql replace text in a field php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866114/mysql-replace-text-in-a-field-php)

Comment: so... if a user already '[pro]' accidentally stumbles on the upgrade path without enough points, it gets taken away from him/her although they already had it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$insert =  "UPDATE users SET rights=' [user]'  WHERE rights=' [pro]' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
```

Try:

```
$insert =  "UPDATE users SET rights=' [pro]' WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";
```

You have two `WHERE` clauses and that won't work. Just update their rights to pro once you take away 50 points.

You could also combine your first and second queries with something like this:

```
$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points`-50), rights = ' [pro]' WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and points > 50";
```

Comment: THank you, worked great! gonna accept, but need to wait 4 min:)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this all in a single query.

```
UPDATE users SET rights=' [pro]', points = points - 50 WHERE username = '$username' AND points >= 50
```

You might also consider adding a condition to only do this when `rights=' [user]'` unless you have some other way in your app to enforce that this upgrade option is only available to people who are not currently "pro".

Answer (score 0):

just to complet Sean sql and your code

replace this in your first query

```
    and points >= 50
```

because if user have 50 he can upgrade to [pro] also.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, not an answer